# Brother MFC-J825DW can't print more than one copy

Tags: print-spooler, brother-printer

My Brother MFC-J825DW printer works fine if I only ask it to print one copy of a document at a time. Any time I ask it to print multiple copies it just sits there and does nothing. The spooler systray icon does show up for 30 seconds or so, but with no documents listed in the queue. Then it disappears. How do I fix this? Here are my specs:

```
    Operating System
        Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
    CPU
        Intel Core 2 Duo E6600 @ 2.40GHz    44 °C
        Conroe 65nm Technology
    RAM
        3.00GB Single-Channel DDR2 @ 333MHz (5-4-4-14)
    Motherboard
        eMachines EMCP73VT-PM (CPU 1)   34 °C
    Graphics
        ASUS VS247 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        767MB GeForce GTX 460 (nVidia)  45 °C
    Hard Drives
        466GB Seagate ST350041 8AS SCSI Disk Device (SATA)  37 °C
    Optical Drives
        HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH41N SCSI CdRom Device
    Audio
        High Definition Audio Device
```

Thank you!

[edit]

I've already updated the firmware to the latest version found [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/download_index.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&dlid=&flang=English&os=93&type2=-1).

Comment: Is this a networked printer or connected via USB?

Comment: It can do both but I chose to use WiFi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with a Brother MFC-8710DW. I found [a blog post](http://www.woodcliffeit.com/blog/?p=89) that suggested a problem with spooling, so I tried this:

- Open Printers and Devices
- Right click on the printer and choose "Printer properties"
- Click the Advanced tab, then select "Print directly to the printer".

After that, I was able to print multiple copies just fine.

I don't know if this will work with other models.

Answer (score -2):

Or Change the Permissions on C:\Windows\Temp folder so that the affected User has Full Control permissions. (Rght Clck on C:\Windows\Temp folder, select Properties then Security Tab and edit Permissions so user has full control.)

Comment: One shouldn't have to change the permissions of `C:\Windows\Temp`, a user should already have read and write permissions to that folder, all data in that folder is suppose to be temporary.  It is not clear to me how changing the permissions of this folder would solve the problem described by the author.

Comment: I am not sure what a user has to do in C:\WINDOWS\temp\.  I would expect it to use %tmp% or %temp% (which may resolve to something like c:\users\username\Appdata\local\temp)